# How to show a Prelaoder/Loading animation/gif/percentage while the included PHP page processes/loads?

Tags: php, html, loading

I'm including a PHP script with in a main PHP page.

Help me "how to show a **Preloader/loading** animation or gif or swf or simply percentage of loading while the included PHP script processes & loads?"
Here is the code snippet where I want to show the same (See the last line of code):

```
<body onLoad="document.forms.form1.from.focus()">
<font face="Calibri">
<table cellpadding="10">
   <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" name="form1">
<tr>
<td width='25%'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter From & To Date</legend>
        <table border='0'>
        <tr>
            <td>From </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="from" /></td>
        </tr>
    </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?  
//Form submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    //No errors, process
    if(!@is_array($error)) 
    {  
 HERE IS WHERE I WANT THE LOADING TO TAKE PLACE
//HERE I INCLUDE THE SCRIPT
```

Also, if i can delay the display of the PHP script until it completes processing.

Comment: There are quite a few bad things in your code: `<font>` is deprecated for a long time now, `@`-error-suppression is often a sign of bad code, using fonts that only exist on modern windows versions, using inline JS (`onload=`) instead of attaching proper event listeners.

Answer (score 3):

Put a `<div>` containing your loading screen right after the `<body>` (or at least before the time-consuming loading happens). At the very end (or after the long part which should be covered by the loading screen) add some JavaScript to hide/remove the div containing the loading screen.

Comment: Plaese give an example for the same, <div> tag code in particular

Answer (score 0):

This is my modified version of a script I got off the internet. Cant remember where I got it from sorry.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapdiv() { 
    //Hide the loading div
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
        document.getElementById('loadingdiv').style.display = 'none'; 
    } else { 
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
            document.loadingdiv.display = 'none'; 
        } else { // IE 4 
            document.all.loadingdiv.style.display = 'none'; 
        } 
    } 

    //Show the results div
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
        document.getElementById('resultdiv').style.display = 'block'; 
    } else { 
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
            document.resultdiv.display = 'block'; 
        } else { // IE 4 
            document.all.resultdiv.style.display = 'block'; 
        } 
    } 

    window.onunload = null;
    return;
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
</form>
<div id='loadingdiv' align='center'><img src='../images/loading.gif' alt='Loading...' title='Loading...' /></div>
<div id='resultdiv' style='display:none;'>
<!-- Do some html stuff here. This div block is hidden until the end of page load -->
<?php
    //Query database
    //Show results
?>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //this is called after page loaded
    window.onload=swapdiv;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The main point of SO is teaching others. A script like this, without additional comments, is pretty worthless in that regard. Could you maybe edit the post to point out the specifics, why does it work the way it works? Etc.

Comment: @Dennis Haarbrink fair comment.What happens when my example page loads is it will show a div (named loadingdiv) on the page and all other elements are hidden (they are in the div named resultdiv). After the page has finished loading, the swapdiv() function at the bottom of the page is called, which hides the div named loadingdiv and makes the resultdiv visible. You can see this effect on webpages like facebook.