# How to show loading gif while page hasn't fully loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have one page called `generate_schedule.php` and within this page I have a form where they user selects from two drop downs and clicks submit (see image below):

[image]

This form POST's the start date and end date to another php called `generate.php`. 
At the moment loading `generate.php` takes about 1-2 minutes long as it is pulling a lot of information from multiple API's. While the page is loading I want to display a loading gif. Currently I have the following code for loading the next page:

```
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
<style type="text/css">
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(images/loading.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut();
    });
</script>
```

However what this doe is that it only appears once `generate.php` has fully loaded for a few seconds. I have also tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() {
     $('.se-pre-con').hide();
  });
</script>
```

But this does not work either it also only appears for a slit second once the `generate.php` page has **fully loaded**

Basically what I want to happen is when I click generate schedule in `generate_schedule.php`, a loading gif appears while `generate.php`is loading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show a Prelaoder/Loading animation/gif/percentage while the included PHP page processes/loads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827699/how-to-show-a-prelaoder-loading-animation-gif-percentage-while-the-included-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show ajax loading gif animation while the page is loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305260/how-to-show-ajax-loading-gif-animation-while-the-page-is-loading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the gif is not showing until the `generate.php` is almost loaded is because when you click the submit button, the form is submitted to `generate.php` and you are no long on the `generate_schedule.php`. But the content is gonna take a long time to load, so the browser prefer to display the `generate_schedule.php` content at the moment, instead of displaying a blank page.

General approach is to put the loader on `generate_schedule.php` page instead on `generate.php`. Display the loader first when click the button, then submit the form, then the page will keep loading content while diplay the loader gif.

So here is something what I usually do:
1. add a hidden element on `generate_schedule.php` like:

```
<div id="loading"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>
```

with the css like (assuming the image is 60px width and 40px height):

```
#loading{
    position: fixed, 
    top: 0; left: 0; 
    width: 100%; height:100%; 
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); 
    z-index: 1000;
    display:none;
}
#loading img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Basically move the loader from `generate.php` to `generate_schedule.php`.
then on the `generate_schedule.php` add javascript as:

```
$('#submitBtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//prevent the form submit
    e.stopPropagation();// stop propagation
    $('#loading').show();
    $('#form').submit();
});
```